# Python regex to find div tag content

Tags: python, regex

What pattern do you write to find the content between the tags?

```
inputData = '<div class="media-story">content and content</div>'
pattern = '<div ???>(.*?)</div>'

pattern_matcher = re.compile(pattern)
```

Comment: as much of a meme as it is - in case you plan to do more than just that with regex (read: parse html with regex), DON'T. use something like beautifulsoup instead.

Comment: Never, ever, use a regex to parse HTML. Unless you can guarantee the HTML is trivial it is essentially impossible to use a regex to reliably parse it. Like MCO said in their comment use package BeautifulSoup or equivalent.

Comment: Agree with you, BeautifulSoup is a good choice to do that, but for other reasons, I need to do that with regex -:). I am done with that and used only regex and worked well -

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```py
import re

data = '<div class="media-story">content and content</div>'
match = re.search(r'<div.*>(.*)<\/div>', data)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

If you want to play around: https://regex101.com/r/wTosNH/1.

Comment: this is not going to work because it will bring all the divs 
we need one that just looks for div with a certain class "media-story"

Comment: That was not clear from the question. Then, you should change ``'<div.*>(.*)<\/div>'`` to ``'<div class=\"media-story\">(.*)<\/div>'`` (assuming you don't have anything like ``id``s or other stuff in your ``div``s). Have you tried playing with the link I provided you?

Comment: seems working on webpage tester - I will update you later -- thank you

Comment: Hi Leopold 
did not work for me when i do it for the full string

https://regex101.com/r/gcp2pG/1

Comment: As I wrote in my comment to the question you should never, ever,  use a regex to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use non-capturing group to capture `>` and `<` and ignore in a match, 
match whatever between them.

```
regex = '(?:>).*(?:<)'
```

[demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I4bIJb/1)

or using look around

```
regex = (?<=>).*(?=<)
```